# Sony Xperia Z Tablet not found by adb

Tags: android, xamarin

I recently got a sony xperia z tabled and would like to deploy/debug my xamarin.droid projects on it.
What I did:
* connected tablet to my dev machine
* Enabled the developer options in the devices settings
* also enabled usb debugging
* then the tablet itself installed drivers on my dev machine and is now recognized by windows explorer and the device manager as "portable device - sony xperia"

So everything seems fine to me.
However, when using "adb devices", the device won't show up.
Even a system restart, tablet restart and "adb kill-server"&"adb start-server" did not help.

Am I missing anything? Can you please give me any hints what I could check additionally or what the problem might be?

I am running windows 8 x64, just in case that matters.

Comment: Hi, have you tried running ADB as administrator? That always catches me out in W7 / W8. Might be a silly question but Eclipse, SDK manager and ADB flake out on me without doing that manually EVERY time!

Comment: Sorry for a second comment: do you have ADB installed with Sony's drivers and another version with the SDK perhaps. They can clash. Every HTC I owned had this issue!

Comment: Have the Sony Xperia Z tablet all the required attributes and restrictions defined in your manifest file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the replies.

Acually I was too f** stupid to install the usb drivers. When enabling usb debugging on the xperia z device, it asks whether it should install the "pc companion software". I thought klicking "ok" would be sufficient to perform the installation. However, this only mounts the installation software on the pc. So you have to actually manually install that stuff. I am just too stupid. Sry. :)

But RossC was actually right as well: After installing several updates on my xperia, the device still did not show up. Running adb with administrative privileges did the job. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have bought a new phone remember to activate the **developer rights**:

Settings -> About Phone -> Build Number

tap 7 times on Build Number and "developer options" will appear on your settings menu.

I tried this method with my Sony Xperia Compact Z3 and works!

Comment: Exactly. And then Windows will pull the proper ADB drivers (in case of Windows usage).