# Eclipse does not recognize Android Device

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My Eclipse does not recognize my Smartphone (Sony Xperia Z), I tried it with an other Smartphone, it worked perfectly without any problems. Using Windows 7. Followed some advices like this one, the List ist empty:

```
C:\IDE\sdk\platform-tools>adb kill-server

C:\IDE\sdk\platform-tools>adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *

C:\IDE\sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
```

I also installed the new driver in "device manager" with the latest usb-driver and also tried to update automaticly. Restarted Eclipse, restarted Computer 10times, no change. I can access on the memory of the device. USB-Debug-Mode is on(restarted it many times). What can I do next?

Comment: Check this link too..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824120/no-compatible-targets-were-found-real-device-eclipse/20824274#20824274

Comment: Once the app is compiled you can download the .apk to your phone by emailing it yourself, or something.  I load it up on my website and download it.  That's how I test all my stuff in development.  I've never plugged in my phone or tablet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Xperia S I had the same problem. The solution for me was to enable `USB tethering`. Don't forget to disable the corresponding network adapter in the `device manager`

Answer (score 0):

Check for USB debugging is checked or not..

if yes then connect and restart adb

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490255/sony-xperia-z-tablet-not-found-by-adb

Hit ^ if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

1) make sure in your device have enabled the "developer mode" in configurations.

2) Make sure that you phone is really a Sony Xperia Z, because fake chinese mobile phone are very similar.

3) Make sure that the cooked room or version of you Android is compatible to develop/debugging

Comment: 1) yes it is 2) yes it´s for sure an original, worked on my friends pc. 3) yes it worked on my friends pc

Comment: then, you try to reinstall you Eclipse ADT ?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes ADB does not recognise some devices, i had a similar issue with some android devices, specially using Windows 8/8.1, my solution was to download a new ADB which comes with a folder calles "Microsoft.VC90.CRT" containing some DLL files, as soon as i replaced the SDK ADB with this new one, all my devices were ready to go.

If you still having issues, let me know to upload the ADB rar.